# Почему, собственно, запятая, а не тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Снова-таки фраза из учебника:

> «Придëт время, и о нëм заговорит весь мир».

Стоят кавычки, потому что это было зацитировано и в учебнике.

Вопрос: почему стоит запятая, а не тире? Вроде должно быть тире, т. к. указывается последовательность действий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) ***Придëт врЕмя**, и о нëм заговорит весь мИр.*

(2) ***ПридЁт время** — и о нëм заговорит весь мир.*

**ССП**, союз ***И*** выражает **временную последовательность** событий. Это соединительно-распространительные отношения, что определяется по лексике.  **[Синтаксис современного языка, стр. 223](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf) .**

В первом варианте временные отношения обозначены **запятой**, но второй вариант **с тире** также возможен (**неосновной** знак в ССП: пауза больше, **ударение** на первом слове).

Comment: В общем, перед _и_ можно ставить как тире, так и запятую, если указывается последовательность?

Comment: Не совсем так, временная последовательность может быть разной. Бывает еще соединительно-перечислительная, там нужна запятая. Чем отличаются? При распространении взаимообусловленность событий больше, там можно и тире поставить, чтобы их подчеркнуть.  А при перечислении этого нет, например:  Дождь кончился, и  небо постепенно прояснилось. Здесь запятая. И на смещение ударения обратите внимание.  Будьте внимательны))